# Netlogo: ask patches in-radius but not the center patch itself

Tags: netlogo

I would like to make things with patches in-radius but excluding the patch with the agent itself, the center patch, so I modify the Myself example from the model library:

```
to splotch
  ask turtles [
    ask one-of patches in-radius 2 with [not any? turtles-here] [
      set pcolor [ color ] of myself
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

but this code also excludes other patches with turtles so it should be something like

```
to splotch
  ask turtles [
    ask one-of patches in-radius 2 [not self][
      set pcolor [ color ] of myself
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

But this code isn't working and I don't figure out how it has to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `other` primitive. However, `other` excludes agents of the same type and you are wanting a turtle to exclude a patch. So, you need to get the relevant patch to `ask` the `other` patches. Here's one approach:

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 3 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  splotch
end

to splotch
  ask turtles
  [ let mycolor color
    ask patch-here
    [ ask other patches in-radius 4
      [ set pcolor mycolor
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

If you want something more like the way you were doing it, you can create a local variable to store the patch and then exclude it like this:

```
to splotch
  ask turtles
  [ let mypatch patch-here
    ask patches in-radius 4 with [self != mypatch]
    [ set pcolor [color] of myself
    ]
  ]
end
```